Package logic in Java project with gradle
I am trying to create a java project using an existing library, but I can't understand exactly the idea of Composite Gradle Build. I have an API project and a webServer project, I want to import API classes to the webServer.
Project estructure
This is the gradle build of api
plugins {
    id 'java-library'
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'application'

group = 'org.dkf.jed2k'
version = '2.0'

description = "jed2k core library"

sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}

test {
    useJUnit()
    maxHeapSize = '1G'
}

dependencies {
    api group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-jdk14', version:'1.7.33'
    implementation 'com.google.re2j:re2j:1.6'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.8'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.7.5'
    testImplementation group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version:'4.13.2'
    testImplementation group: 'org.mockito', name: 'mockito-core', version: '2.0.111-beta'
}

This is the gradle build of webServer
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.2.4'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.4'
}


group = 'org.dkf.jed2k'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

java {
    sourceCompatibility = '17'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral();
}

dependencies {

    implementation(":core")
    //implementation files('/home/david/Documents/jed2k/core/build/libs/core-2.0.jar')
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
}
tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

bootRun {
    systemProperties = System.properties
}

I have assembled the current project following a guide, but I still don't understand exactly how to integrate "org.dkf.jed2k" with the extra folders I added, or if it's a mistake when naming it or adding it to the build.

You want to import api into webServer using a composite build.
To do this, add api as an included build in webServer's settings.gradle:
includeBuild '../api'

Now the outgoing artifacts of api will be available to webServer. This means you can add the line:
dependencies {
   implementation 'org.dkf.jed2k:api:2.0'
}

and api's classes should be available in webServer's code.
Update: it looks from your image like you may have changed the name of api to jed2k in that project's settings.gradle. In that case, you will need to use:
dependencies {
   implementation 'org.dkf.jed2k:jed2k:2.0'
}


it keeps telling me it can't find "org.dkf.jed2k", I will look at the documentation, but thanks for the comment, inside the setting.grandle, does it matter how I name it?

Right, it looks like you've changed the name? I've updated the answer.
